# Is there a SQL function that allows me to run a query with dates / times that automatically update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am writing a query that needs to be run every week on friday. The query needs to be automated in python to where the query pulls the same data from the MS SQL server on a weekly basis. I need the dates to reflect the weekly dates automatically with a time delta or something. Here is my idea of what I need to do but I can't seem to get it right.

In python, I can easily do this with a `(date.today - timedelta(days=7))` statement. However, when I try and update the query using a sql date function, `getdate() - dateadd(day,-7,getdate)`, I receive incorrect data.

Here is my code:

```
select (query)
from (datatable) dt
where dt.transaction_time >= dateadd(day,-7, dt.transaction_time)
```

I have tried variations to the code but still no results.
where `getdate() >= dateadd(day,-7, dt.transaction_time)................... where getdate() >= dateadd(day,-7, getdate())

Help on this would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: So the question is not at all related to python ?

Comment: You are comparing, on each row, the `transaction_time` to the same column - 7 days.  That's never going to work.

Comment: the report is automatically run through python sorry!

Comment: Any idea on how I can fix this other than creating a new column?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly 7 days ago from *this moment*:

```
...
WHERE dt.transaction_time >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE());
```

Exactly 7 days ago from *today at midnight*:

```
DECLARE @d datetime = DATEADD(DAY, -7, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()));

...
WHERE dt.transaction_time >= @d;
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked! Excellent

Comment: I seem to remember a case I had that `someDateTimeValue >= CONVERT(date, someValue)` ends up with a weird `RangeSeek` using the classic `Constant Scan` `Merge Interval` setup, and that it was better to explicitly cast it back to `datetime` if the other side of the comparison was a `datetime`. Can you confirm if that's the case? Might be just mis-remembering

Comment: @Charlieface I know there are some weird statistics issues if you convert the left side to date explicitly but I don't recall seeing any odd symptoms with this pattern.

Comment: Then how do you explain [these query plans](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c681bfd3016e2e8b9f5989926d3fc087)? Yes, that case was a bit different, it wasn't so much statistics as a case of reading too many rows, because it reads the whole previous day, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/220697.

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, I didn't remember that specific question, sorry, and I thought it still had everything to do with the cast on the left hand side. Updated the answer, ok? Even though the OP hasn't even stated the data type of `transaction_time`.

Comment: I actually thought you should leave in the explanation of same day vs same moment, better to see both options. You could do `CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AS datetime)` instead. Honestly don't get upset, I don't know if I'm right or not anyway. It *could* be that that particular instance will use correct ranges, I haven't tested it and was looking to you as being more of an expert in this. I'd love to see you do a proper article on this. I did upvote you before also.

Comment: @Charlieface Not upset, just don't want to turn every simple answer to a poorly spec'd question into a dissertation. OP is using python. Even if you're right it's highly unlikely they'd ever notice the ramifications.